# SELECT COUNT(*) not working with LIKE %

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I currently have the following:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE quality LIKE :quality AND type LIKE :type AND name LIKE :name ".$amount);
$stmt->bindParam(':quality', $quality);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $type);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
```

This will always return 1. Yet when doing:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE quality LIKE :quality AND type LIKE :type AND name LIKE :name ".$amount
```

It will return all the items that match the query. When doing a broad search the LIKE's will be set to % rather than an actual name due to a search box.

Is this an issue with the LIKE %? I'm needing to get how many items there are within that query so I can see the total amount of pages by doing

```
$pages = ceil($total / $limit);
```

$amount is the following:

```
if ($_GET['amount'] == "2") { $amount = "AND points <=".$result[0]['points']; }
```

Comment: What is this:  ` . . . LIKE :name ".$amount);`?

Comment: Sorry, included that in the main post now.

Comment: If the comment of Gordon isn't clear enough : What is this:  `. . . LIKE :name ".$amount);` ? You end up with `LIKE something something` which is wrong and probably the cause of your issue. You should have `LIKE something`... meaning `:name` or `$amount` but not both

Comment: The problem is that you do your query and return the _rowCount_ . This will always be 1 as you are using an aggregate function (ie, COUNT) with no GROUP BY clause. So your query has brought back a single row with a column which has the count in it, but then instead of using that count you have instead counted the number of rows returned.

Comment: Thanks, doing fetchColumn worked instead.